# Why the group $\langle x,y\mid x^3, y^3, yxyxy\rangle$ is not trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

This comes from Artin Second Edition, page 219. Artin defined  $G=\langle x,y\mid x^3, y^3, yxyxy\rangle$ , and uses the Todd-Coxeter Algorithm to show that the subgroup $h=\langle y\rangle$  has index 1, and therefore he gets $G=H$ is the cyclic group of order 3.

My question is: why $\langle y\rangle$ is not trivial? The Todd-Coxeter Algorithm gives no extra information about $y$  except it acts trivially on $\langle y\rangle$ as any other elements in $G$ do. So how do we know that $y\neq 1$?

Many thanks!

Comment: In $G$, if we add the relation $x=e$ we get the cyclic group of order $3$.  Hence $G$ can not be trivial.

Comment: I could equally well ask you why you think $G$ is trivial. The fact that $G = \langle y \rangle$ just proves that it is a cyclic group generated by $y$. We know that $y^3$ is the identity in $G$, so that tells us that $|G|=1$ or $3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt " |G|=1 or 3", that's where I get confused (why not 1?), it seems that lulu gives an good answer.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! But if the relations get more complex, how can we know the actual order of the subset we choose?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  In general, there is no way to sort out the structure of a group from its generators and relations.  In specific cases, as here, we might be able to do it, but there certainly isn't a general algorithmic approach.

Comment: Kill $x$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: The map $x\mapsto (),y\mapsto (1,2,3)$ is easily checked to be a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_3$, whose image is cyclic of order $3$. So the group cannot be trivial. (In general such homomorphisms are harder to find.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The group $G$ is cyclic of order $3$, generated by the element $y$.

Here are two proofs. Both are pretty similar, the main difference is how you conclude that the group is non-trivial (implicit in the first, explicit in the second).

---

**First proof: Presentations.** Add in the new generator $z:=yx$, and then remove $x$ via the relevant Tietze transformation to get:
$$\langle y, z\mid (y^{-1}z)^3, y^3, z^2y\rangle.$$
We then see that the group is cyclic, generated by $z$ (as $y=z^{-2}$). So lets find the relevant presentation:
$$\langle z\mid (z^3)^3, (z^2)^3\rangle=\langle z\mid z^9, z^6\rangle.$$
This simplifies to:
$$\langle z\mid z^3\rangle.$$
Then it is generated by $y$ as $z=yx$ is a generator, and therefore so is $y=(xy)^{-2}$.

---

**Second proof: Use the abelianisation.** By the relation $yxyxy$, we see that $y^{-1}\in\langle yx\rangle$, and so $x, y\in\langle yx\rangle$. Therefore, $yx$ generates our group $G=\langle x, y\rangle$. This means that $G$ is abelian, so $(yx)^3=y^3x^3=1$. Therefore, $G$ is either cyclic of order three or trivial. As the comments to the question point out, the map which kills $x$ has non-trivial image, and so $G$ is non-trivial. Therefore, $G$ is cyclic of order $3$, and generated by $yx$. Conclude that $G=\langle y\rangle$ as in the first proof (or by noting that the map which kills $x$ much be an isomorphism, so $x$ is trivial and so $yx=y$).

Comment: 3rd proof: $y^3=yxyxy=1$ can be written $y^3=y^{-1}xyx=1$, that is, $y^3=1$ and $y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}$. The latter relation implies $y^{-3}xy^3=x^{-1}$, which along with $y^3=1$ implies $x^2=1$. Combined with $x^3=1$, this forces $x=1$. Once $x=1$, the presentation becomes $\langle y|y^3\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to find the hidden rule that almost everyone neglects.

**Page 219**

*We stop the process when an operation has been determined that is consistent with
the rules.*

It's to say, before we determine $y$, the process has stopped

so even you get $y=1$ after getting $x=1$, it's not in accordance with the rules, or it's overdone to collapse the group